# MCU Based Video Processor

Tags: computer-architecture, video

**EDIT:** Clarify scope of question.

I am planning to create a homemade Z80 computer.
One thing I have been disappointed with about other designs is the lack of color graphic output, they all had text mode or rarely monochrome graphic output.

My idea is to create a 32 Color QQVGA (160x120) or 16 Color QVGA (320x240) GPU of sorts, using MCUs such as ATMEL or Microchip offers in the ATMega and PIC lineups. It should be able to output over either Composite or VGA.

The main issue is getting useful data from the Z80 to this homemade GPU. How would I send sprite data, color selection, and screen position so that this GPU wouldn't use too much address space.

The color palettes that I am aiming to implement are the [DB16/DB32 palettes](https://github.com/geoffb/dawnbringer-palettes).

*Old post in spoiler below.*

> I am looking to design a video processor for a homebrew z80 computer design. I am planning to output in VGA using an Atmel ATMega 328. My concern is how to implement a graphical mode. I have 13 available registers to work with (Other three for text only output). How can I do 16/32 color sprites at VGA and half VGA resolutions? Any implementation ideas would be great.

Comment: Output VGA using Atmega328? Ambitious.. Do you know how VGA works?

Comment: I should be able to implement VGA easily. It's coming up with a useful data format from the Z80 to the GPU that is the challenge.

Comment: Do you know that the pixel clock frequency for VGA is ~25MHz? And the maximum operating frequency of ATMega328 is 20MHz? Or you have something in your setup you are not telling us?

Comment: While you may be able to get a stable low-horizontal-resolution image on a VGA monitor with an ATmega, you will hardly be implementing VGA in a conventional sense, and you don't begin to have enough memory to do bitmapped/framebuffer graphics.  Do some reading online and you will find this needs a more carefully selected MCU, an FPGA, or dedicated video parts.  It's not out of the question that you could drive an old ISA VGA card.

Comment: *"from the Z80 to the GPU"*? Tell us more about this GPU you mentioned. Which IC?

Comment: @dim Updated question to reflect goal of creating and implementing homemade GPU.

Comment: Consider a MIPI-DBI style LCD, like one with internal RAM and sys80-like or 6800-line interface? Because those LCDs has the logic built in, so that you don't need to do anything if your display does not change, the internal RAM and logic handles  the refresh.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't understand the architecture. It's clearer now. Well, I'd say the same as all others, and strongly support the FPGA solution (maybe even a CPLD is enough, with an external RAM for the frame buffer). This is the kind of problems it is meant to solve. And it's fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen ARM-based embedded processors do something akin to your requirements. Something like ST's STM32F407, clocking at 168 MHz can generate VGA video by using direct-memory-access (DMA) feeding local RAM into serial-out GPIO pins. What I saw was not colour (BW 640x480), but your lower-resolution requirements should allow coarse colour output. Sync signal and DMA requests were timed with on-chip timers. Enough horsepower was available to do all the video processing, mouse & keyboard interface plus a lot more - certainly enough to do fast sprite processing.
This processor is considerably more powerful than your Z80, and also considerably more difficult to program. Without any hardware assistance, a very capable general-purpose processor is required .
 A dedicated Z80 could do video VGA, but would need *at least some* hardware assistance. I'd guess that this dedicated Z80 might have enough horsepower to do sprite processing, depending on how you do the hardware assist. Details of that hardware assist are too complex to outline here.
Microcontrollers generally don't have enough RAM for frame buffer(s), at least not the simpler ones in the ATMEL or Microchip lineup that can only access on-chip RAM. And they don't have enough I/O bandwidth anyway, for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The [Uzebox](http://uzebox.org) does this by overclocking a ATmega644 to 28,636 MHz. This works, have built some of these. Of course, it has all the game logic inside, too, so you wouldn't need your Z80 then.

Answer (score 0):

An Atmega328 is too slow to generate VGA signal on the fly. So, you'd need an external video driver chip that integrates a framebuffer, and a DAC. At that point, you'd notice the Atmega has too little RAM (by FAR) to even buffer a single frame...

So, in other words, I call "nonsense" on your "I should be able to implement VGA easily" claim.

What you'd want to have is something that either has the speed to calculate each VGA frame on the fly from whatever representation of the scene is stored within its buffers, or something with enough RAM to buffer two full frames, and let the DAC generate one frame while the CPU renders the other, then swap the two buffers ("blitting"). In any case, your Atmega is not the right device, unless you go for non-VGA resolutions (i.e. really low), or find an interesting way to address e.g. external DRAM and feed a DAC directly off that (which would certainly be an interesting feat, and far from "no problem").

Comment: Yes in general, though many simple VGA driver projects don't use a DAC but merely treat each color as on or off.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, hm, yeah, with that in mind and abusing hardware-SPI, one mind achieve something like a reasonable pixel clock, but then I'd argue you'd hardly be "implementing VGA"

Comment: Updated question. More concerned about feasibility and implementation using any off the shelf micro-controller.

Comment: "The main issue is getting data from ZPU to GPU" <- as explained, that is not true.